# how to run HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT Project on android Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

My Project is in HTML 5, CSS3,JavaScript. My project is perfectly work in internet browser(either using localhost or server)

Now i want to run my project on android Emulator. i am using http://'localhost':8036/login  or  http://'AndroidLocalhostipaddress':8036/login to run project on browser. and also try to copy my project in asset folder(web-view technique)but it is not work? 
My project correctly work in iPad(iPhone) but in Android it not work.

First tell me any code conversion required to run on Emulator.

Comment: First make a build ( I suggest phonegap ).

Comment: Tyagi if i copy my project folder in asset folder and using webview concept,it work or not?

Comment: Well no idea about webview. But you can make a zip of your project and go to https://build.phonegap.com/ create an free account and upload your zip file and make a build ( .apk file for android or any other platform). That will easily run on your emulator as well as any android phone. ( NOTE : Make sure your project only have HTML, CSS and Javascript files only )

Comment: your html and other file is on server or in local db?

Comment: local machine..i am developing project in elipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a WebView view in your layout XML file:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_webview 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

use this code in your activity onCreate() method:

```
WebView mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And, `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");` works under all API levels.

I still not figure out why `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/myfile.html");` works only on API level 8. But it doesn't matter now.

try this code. hope it helps you.

Comment: Ankxx13 this for only one html page.but in my project total 267 html files and also more than 100 css and javascript files.then what to do now?

Comment: @priyashivale Do you want the whole website of yours in your android application ? is that what you want to do ?

Comment: no my project is mobile apps.my project correctly work in iphone.for time being i have access my project through browser using localhost.

Comment: Ankxx13 is there any possibility. i have copied my project folder in asset folder and run it through webview load url.and give path of main form.but still it not work.

Comment: @priyashivale please post your code that you have tried to do so far. cant able to say anything beside seeing your code. hope you understand.

Comment: can simply tell me how to convert existing(html CSS JavaScript)project in android.and this project developed in eclipse.

Comment: Yes you can go to build.phonegap.com create an free account and upload your zip file and make a build ( .apk file for android or any other 7 platforms). That will easily run on your emulator as well as any android phone.

Comment: @AnkitDhadse How does this solution use the CSS and Javascript files though?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) Project?

Maybe requires some work on setup but I believe that it will work for your case.